# How to convert between ByteString and Storable Vector?

Tags: haskell

What is the best way to convert between `Storable.Vector Word8` and a strict `ByteString`?

Of course a non-copying (no-op) way would be most appreciated.

Should I just `unsafeCoerce` or is there a library function for that (I couldn't find one)?

Also, will the approach be the same for an `Unboxed.Vector Word8`?

Comment: In some cases it would be beneficial to copy.  If your bytestrings are short segments of a longer original bytestring, e.g. (`BS.take 10 someLongByteString`), the entire long chunk will be retained by the `ForeignPtr`.  In this case copying is often better because it'll use much less memory.  This is sort of a specialized case, but it seems to come up often.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A simple `unsafeCoerce` will not work, as the layout of the data constructors is different:

```
data StorableArray i e = StorableArray !i !i Int !(ForeignPtr e)
```

vs.

```
data ByteString = PS {-# UNPACK #-} !(ForeignPtr Word8) -- payload
                     {-# UNPACK #-} !Int                -- offset
                     {-# UNPACK #-} !Int                -- length
```

You can import `Data.Array.Storable.Internals` and `Data.ByteString.Internal` to get access to the raw constructors and then construct one out of the other without copying the data:

```
> let bs = pack [1,2,3]
> bs
"\SOH\STX\ETX"
> let sa = case bs of (PS ptr 0 n) -> StorableArray 0 (n-1) n ptr
> :t sa
sa :: StorableArray Int GHC.Word.Word8
> Data.Array.MArray.readArray sa 1
2
> Data.Array.MArray.readArray sa 0
1
> Data.Array.MArray.readArray sa 3
*** Exception: Ix{Int}.index: Index (3) out of range ((0,2))
```

(I removed the rather long prompt of `Prelude Data.Array.Storable.Internals Data.ByteString.Internal Data.ByteString>`).

This will not work for `Data.Vector.Unboxed`, because here the data is on the Haskell heap and managed by the GHC runtime, while the other two manage the data outside the Haskell heap.

Answer (score 5):

```
byteStringToVector :: (Storable a) => BS.ByteString -> V.Vector a
byteStringToVector bs = vec where
    vec = V.unsafeFromForeignPtr (castForeignPtr fptr) (scale off) (scale len)
    (fptr, off, len) = BS.toForeignPtr bs
    scale = (`div` sizeOfElem vec)

sizeOfElem vec = sizeOf (undefined `asTypeOf` V.head vec)
```

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/spool/0.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Storable-ByteString.html

Comment: Thanks for putting that on Hackage!