# How to do memory mapped IO on custom data types?

Tags: haskell, mmap

#### The Setup

I recently implemented `mmap` based file reading and directly ran into strange behavior. The relevant code is:

```
-- | map whole aedat file into memory and return it as a vector of events
-- TODO what are the finalizing semantics of this?
mmapAERData :: S.Storable a => FilePath -> IO (S.Vector (AER.Event a))
mmapAERData name = do
    -- mmap file into memory and find the offset behind the header
    bs <- dropHeader <$> mmapFileByteString name Nothing
    -- some conversion is necessary to get the 'ForeignPtr' from
    -- a 'ByteString'
    B.unsafeUseAsCString bs $ \ptr -> do
      fptr <- newForeignPtr_ ptr
      let count = B.length bs `div` 8 -- sizeof one event
      return $ S.unsafeFromForeignPtr0 (castForeignPtr fptr) count
```

[→ code in context](https://github.com/fhaust/aer/blob/master/src/Data/AER/AEDat.hs#L36-L47)

Some explanation: The AEDat Format is basically a long list of two Word32s. One encodes the *address* the other the *timestamp*. Before that there are some lines of header text that I drop in the `dropHeader` function. I could do this directly on a `ForeignPtr` if absolutely necessary, but I prefer to use the common function that works on `ByteStrings` instead.

The the `Storable` instances can be found [here](https://github.com/fhaust/aer/blob/master/src/Data/AER/Types.hs#L57-L66) and [here](https://github.com/fhaust/aer/blob/master/src/Data/AER/DVS128.hs#L48-L54). I am not sure about the *alignment* here, but I suspect that an alignment of 8 should be correct.

#### The Problem

Reading the data works quite well, but after some time the memory seems to get corrupted somehow:

```
>>> es <- DVS.mmapDVSData "dataset.aedat" 
>>> es S.! 1000
Event {address = Address {polarity = D, posX = 6, posY = 50}, timestamp = 74.771407s}
>>> :type es
es :: S.Vector (DVS.Event DVS.Address)
>>> _ <- evaluate (V.convert es :: V.Vector (DVS.Event DVS.Address))
>>> es S.! 1000
Event {address = Address {polarity = D, posX = 0, posY = 44}, timestamp = 0s}
```

Apparently accessing all elements of `es` somehow corrupts my memory. Or the garbage collector recycles it? Either way, this is strange. What can I do about that?

Comment: I suspect this is because of the strange way you're converting the `ByteString`  to a `Vector`.  Does it work if you do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682527/how-to-convert-between-bytestring-and-storable-vector#answer-18888945) (where you keep the same `ForeignPtr`)?

Comment: I strongly would suggest using https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmap-0.5.9/docs/System-IO-MMap.html#v:mmapFileByteString

Comment: This is not an answer, because I haven't investigated for real, but: the body of your `unsafeUseAsCString` looks fishy to me. It's typical that the callback you give functions of this kind should not return anything that references the pointer it's given as an argument; but your return value references `fptr` which references `ptr`. Are you double-sure that doing this is okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mmapFileByteString` performs a `mmap`, which creates a `ForeignPtr`, and sticks that `ForeignPtr` into a `ByteString`.  `unsafeUseAsCString` coerces the `ForeignPtr` into a `Ptr`, from which you then create a new `ForeignPtr`.  Then you take that second `ForeignPtr` and use it with `S.unsafeFromForeignPtr0` to create a vector.

Having two `ForeignPtr`s pointing at the same memory is a no no.  The GHC runtime treats them as two separate objects.  After all references to the `ByteString` are gone, the finalizer for its`ForeignPtr` will be called, deallocating the `mmap` and reclaiming the underlying memory.  This leaves the second `ForeignPtr` pointing at an invalid region.

The solution here is to use [`Data.ByteString.Internal.toForeignPtr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.9.1.4/docs/Data-ByteString-Internal.html#v%3AtoForeignPtr) to extract and re-use the `ForeignPtr` from the `ByteString`.  Replace the `unsafeUseAsCString` block with this:

```
let (fptr,offset,len) = Data.ByteString.Internal.toForeignPtr bs
-- it might be worthwhile to assert that offset == 0
let count = len `div` 8
return $ S.unsafeFromForeignPtr0 (castForeignPtr fptr) count
```

IMHO, the real solution here is not to fiddle with all this stuff at all.  Just conventionally read the file into a `ByteString`, pull out 8-byte substrings from that and manually conver them into `Event`s.  All this `mmap` and `ForeignPtr` stuff is dangerous, and not a whole lot faster than doing things safely and correctly.  If you want absolute fastest performance without regard to safety, program in C.

Comment: "Just conventionally read the file into a `ByteString`... All this `mmap` stuff is dangerous and not a whole lot faster." Do you have evidence for this claim? I would have expected that if you want to access a few events at random positions from a very large file, this way would be significantly faster than reading in the whole file.

Comment: By the way, despite my nitpick, this looks like a great answer based on really expert knowledge.

Comment: If the file is too big, use [hseek](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.5.0.0/docs/GHC-IO-Handle.html#v:hSeek) and read 8 bytes out of it.  This is essentially what the OS does when you read from an mmap'ed region of memory.

Comment: Using hseek would certainly be one way, but it's not as modular: it means that functions that access the big data structure have to be aware that they're accessing something that came from a file (rather than, say, a dynamically generated vector or a vector that came from parsing something on the network or whatever). Pretty much all the arguments for memory mapping in other languages apply equally well here.

Comment: All programmers, as part of software engineering practice, have to settle on a compromise between safety, simplicity, modularity, and performance in their code design.  The older I get, the closer I hang out to the "safety" pole.

Comment: I'm fine with making observations about tradeoffs, and even judgment calls about tradeoffs. All I'm saying is that you seem to be misrepresenting the tradeoff by downplaying the good things about memory mapping, which makes your judgment call sound disingenuous.

Comment: You can still use the mmap'ed `ByteString` without directly touching any icky `ForeignPtr`s by creating a pure `readEvent :: ByteString -> Int -> Event` function.

Comment: "`mmap` is dangerous" → I wouldn't have considered it if reading all events into memory wouldn't have blown up in memory several times. "`toForeignPtr`" I searched for a function like that, but apparently it is not visible anymore in the current version of `bytestring`?

Comment: The module is there on the most recent version on [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.6.0), and you can import Data.ByteString.Internal with no problem.  The API docs have the 'hide' attribute set so they aren't autogenerated and on hackage, because the implementors view the functions there as not part of the stable API.

Comment: I always thought those "blackened" modules where somehow not available. Re: "If you want absolute fastest performance without regard to safety, program in C." I am glad to say that I have a pure Haskell codebase and I'd rather not change that :)

Comment: And just to add this: I think now that this (hopefully) working I think it is safer to use than using C for the same task. Sure there are some *undefined behavior* cases when dealing with mmapped files, but `mmapAERFile` goes from filename to **immutable** vector of events. All the memory delocation is handled by the garbage collector. I consider this quite safe to use.

Comment: You could take a layer of complexity out by using [mmapFileForeignPtr](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmap-0.5.9/docs/System-IO-MMap.html#v:mmapFileForeignPtr) to directly get a ForeignPtr, without depending on undocumented ByteString internals.